# Having trouble having a loading bar show with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

first time asking a question here, not a professional by any means.

i have a form that when you click the submit button, it scrapes info using that scraper.php.

content being scraped sometimes takes a few seconds (10~) to load, so i want to have a loading gif display while it scrapes.

i created a div with the loading bar, and styled it with css, and set it to display none; however it never shows up when you click submit.

below is the js code as well as another 'older' version of the code i was trying to use to get it to work. Any help would be VERY much appreciated.

```
$("#search").submit(function(e) {
    $('#wait').show();
    var url = "scraper.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#search").serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 
            render (data); 
            $('#wait').hide();
        }

    });
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
```

and here is the old code i tried as well:

```
$("#search").submit(function(e) {
var url = "scraper.php";
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: url,
 beforeSend: function() { $('#wait').show(); },
 complete: function() { $('#wait').hide(); },
 data: $("#search").serialize(),
       success: function (data) { render (data); }

});
```

and here is the respective HTML & CSS code:

```
<div id="wait"></div>

#wait {
display:    none;
position:   fixed;
z-index:    1000;
top:        0;
left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use in your website?

Comment: You have a missing `});`. The one you have matches the inner `({` which is that of the `ajax` method; and the block opened with `.submit(function(e) {` remains unclosed. If this is not a copy-paste issue, try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, see:

```js
function showwait() {
  $('#wait').show();
}
```

```css
#wait {
display:    none;
position:   fixed;
z-index:    1000;
top:        0;
left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wait"></div>

<button onclick="showwait();">Show</button>
```

What you need to do is move the `$('#wait').show();` part to the start of your function like so:

```
$("#search").submit(function(e) {
  $('#wait').show();
  var url = "scraper.php";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    complete: function() { $('#wait').hide(); },
    data: $("#search").serialize(),
    success: function (data) { render (data); }
  });
});
```

Comment: Or it might have been the missing closing `});` for the `ajax` method (added now).

Comment: Perfect! i think the issue was that i was using brackets locally with MAMP and for whatever reason ive been having so much problems with edits made showing up properly with live preview. i pushed your code changes into a live version and it's working as intended. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have it. I would change a couple of things about the CSS though. Here is a JSFiddle using your code showing how you can do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/aep4hguh/

CSS

```
#wait {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8) url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Javascript

```
// Mimic Ajax Call
var submitForm = function() {
    $('#wait').show();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: ' https://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() {
        // Mimic wait
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wait').hide();
        alert('DONE!');
      }, 5000)
    }
  })
}

$('button').on('click', submitForm)
```

HTML

```
<div id="wait"></div>
<button>
  Submit Form
</button>
```